# Possibility to track multiple entries of same ARReferenceImage on iOS 11.3 beta, xCode 9.3 beta, ARKit 1.5

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, arkit, beta

In iOS SDK  iOS 11.3 beta, xCode 9.3 beta, 
ARKit 1.5 gives us the [possibility](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/arkit/recognizing_images_in_an_ar_experience%22possibility%22) to track reference images via camera in the same way we did it with ARToolKit or Vuforia.

The question is, can I track the count of entries of the exact same reference image and put some shape on the top of each one, as if they are separate items? The [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/arkit/recognizing_images_in_an_ar_experience%22possibility%22) states:

> When you run a world-tracking AR session and specify ARReferenceImage objects for the session configuration's detectionImages property, ARKit searches for those images in the real-world environment. When the session recognizes an image, it automatically adds to its list of anchors an ARImageAnchor for each detected image.

I was able to feed my ARWorldTrackingConfiguration with three exactly same images (but rotated differently) but it only found first hit image (they are printed on a piece of paper in matrix-like view). Does this mean that I will only be able to track first hit for each unique reference Image?

If we have the list of anchors we can possibly try to calculate if this is not the same exact spot and maybe try to force it search further?

Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 4):

I'm pretty sure that it isn't possible to track multiple occcurences of the same image straight out of the box, as when an image is detected it is given an ARImageAnchor and this only occurs once:

> If your AR experience adds virtual content to the scene when an image is detected, that action will by default happen only once. To allow the user to experience that content again without restarting your app, call the session’s remove(anchor:) method to remove the corresponding ARImageAnchor:
>   After the anchor is removed, ARKit will add a new anchor the next time
>   it detects the image.

*Having said this*, you could potentially track the number of times an images is shown by manually removing it's ARImageAnchor after a certain period of time by using this built in function:

```
func remove(anchor: ARAnchor)
```

I don't think this would work however if you had the same image within the frostrum of the camera at the same time though.

All things aside, hopefully this example may help you on your way...

Create two variables (one to store the detection count and one to store the anchors):

```
   var anchors = [ARImageAnchor]()
   var countOfDetectedImages = 0
```

Then:

```
  func renderer(_ renderer: SCNSceneRenderer, didAdd node: SCNNode, for anchor: ARAnchor) {

    //1. If Out Target Image Has Been Detected Than Get The Corresponding Anchor
    guard let currentImageAnchor = anchor as? ARImageAnchor else { return }

    //2. Store The ARImageAnchors
    anchors.append(currentImageAnchor)

    //3. Get The Targets Name
    let name = currentImageAnchor.referenceImage.name!

    print("Image Name = \(name)")

    //4. Increase The Count If The Reference Image Is Called Target
    if name == "target"{

        countOfDetectedImages += 1

        print("\(name) Has Been Detected \(countOfDetectedImages)")

            //6. Remove The Anchor
            DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + 3) {
                self.augmentedRealitySession.remove(anchor: anchor)
        }
    }

}
```

And for a total reset of the variables:

```
 /// Removes All The ARImageAnchors & The Detected Count
func removeAllAnchorsAndResetCount(){

    countOfDetectedImages = 0
    anchors.forEach{ augmentedRealitySession.remove(anchor: $0) }
    anchors.removeAll()
}
```

**Possible WorkAround:**

FYI, there are some notes in the [`Apple Documentation`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/arkit/arreferenceimage) which has init methods for:

> init(CGImage, orientation: CGImagePropertyOrientation, physicalWidth: CGFloat):

*Creates a new reference image from a Core Graphics image object.*

> init(CVPixelBuffer, orientation: CGImagePropertyOrientation,
>   physicalWidth: CGFloat)

*Creates a new reference image from a Core Video pixel buffer.*

So 'perhaps' and I haven't looked into this, you may be able to work with the orientation that way?

Comment: Thank you for your reply! I will process the information that you provided. Need to try at least few possible solutions and find the most suitable. For now, you have confirmed my thought, that it won't be possible out of the box :) Cheers.